# Publish Subscribe from WCF to Android, Iphone, WP7

Tags: iphone, android, wcf, push-notification, publish-subscribe

Is there a framework that supports publishing (pushing) messages from a WCF service (REST or SOAP) to various clients like IPhone, Android and WP7?  I'm thinking I can use the WSDualHttpBinding to do dual communication between WCF and WP7.  However, I'm assuming WSDualHttpBinding is not supported in the other two platforms since is not a WS-* standard and there's a lot of stuff that WCF does to establish a receiving channel on the client side.  Is there any other way to accomplish this? How would I about rolling my own?

I'm thinking about exposing my WCF service as a restful endpoint and implement a COMET style pub/sub and calling it good.

I'm stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you end up using ? I have the same question at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this "Cloud to Device Messaging", C2DM, yesterday and thought it may serve your question:

http://www.makeurownrules.com/archives/category/android

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a solution for WP7, you could probably use urbanairship.com to handle the pushes for iPhone and Android. I've used them on a prior project with good results. (I don't work for them.)

Comment: I looked at that option but that still doesn't solve my problem.  I'm thinking maybe windows Azure service bus might do what I want

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)? It'll fallback gracefully from WebSockets & Server-Side Events through to long polling. There's a mono implementation of the client-side library.

We're successfully using it in a large-scale realtime application and it works a treat. A bit further down [this](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) page it details how to communicate with clients from outside the SignalR infrastructure which may be useful if you want to talk to clients from your WCF service.

Cheers,
Dean